# Tobit model: Left and right censoring

Tags: r, regression, censoring, tobit-regression

In my data, my outcome variable `days.to.event` is conceptually left censored at 0 days and right censored at 30 days. However, since the `days.to.event` is a continuous variable, it takes values between 0 and 1 (e.g., 0.025, 0.30... days) as well as between 29 and 30 days (e.g., 29.01...29.35 days). When fitting a `tobit` model (e.g.,`censReg` in R ), how do I specify the left and right censoring? Can I still say 0 for left and 30 for right?